# How to check whether my image is RGB format or BGR format in python? How do i convert them and viceversa?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library, opencv

I am doing some preprocessing  things on pretrained data in OpenVino model.
It says it only uses the BGR format image.

Here ,
***How do i check in python whether my image is in BGR format or RBG format?***

my loaded image code is as

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

image = cv2.imread('29101878_988024658021087_5045014614769664000_o.jpg')
print(image.shape)
```

Gives output of 
shape `(973,772,3)`

***How do i check image is RBG or BGR format?
If it is in RBG format How do i convert it to BGR and viceversa?***

Comment: If you read an image, or video, with OpenCV, it will be BGR. Pretty much everything else (PIL/Pillow, skimage, CImg, ImageMagick, SciPy, NumPy, vips, GD) uses RGB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use opencv (imread, VideoCapture), the images are loaded in the BGR color space.

Reference : 
`Note: In the case of color images, the decoded images will have the channels stored in B G R order.`

**Link :** https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#imread)

To convert you can use

```
rgb_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```

and vice versa.

Comment: Does cv2.imread() automatically converts RGB format image to BGR and that matplotlib.image mpimg automatically  converts to RGB?

Comment: Hey @razzOn2bull, I don't have much context here. But since the default final image will be BGR, I think cv2.imread() converts the image from any format to BGR.

Comment: @razzOn2bull: I think the main takeaway from this answer is "read the documentation".

Comment: Thanks :)  @martineau got it.some articles says opencv always take the image into  bgr format, which we can can change as using cv2.COLOR_BGR2RBG format . I had also used cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR , when i show bgr and rbg images. bgr shows quite blue image while rbg show good image. 

but when import some image 
image = cv2.imread('29101878_988024658021087_5045014614769664000_o.jpg')

and used cv2.imshow(image) 

Its shows clear like rbg image. Anyway  got small intution

Answer (score 2):

To check if the image is in RGB or BGR format we can use:

```
import cv2
from PIL import Image

image = cv2.imread('image path')
img = Image.fromarray(image)
img.mode
```

Comment: This doesnt seem to work. I tested with `cv2.cvtColor()` and it seems like it always says RGB